# How to get Justice Points in WoW

Tags: world-of-warcraft

According to [WoWWiki](http://www.wowwiki.com/Justice_Point) and several other websites, Justice Points are rewards for participating in normal and heroic dungeons that match the character level.

I've been doing random dungeons using dungeon finder since lv15. I am now lv65 and have been in 20+ instance runs, but didn't receive a single Justice Point, nor did I find any place on the game interface that mentions anything about them.

Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: Have you checked you character's currency? And I dodn't mean gold.

Comment: I really wouldn't use WowWiki. It's not up-to-date and not officially supported by Blizzard. WowHead is the best place to be. I have it set as my homepage

Comment: @Sandokan Yes I have. Character panel, Currency tab.

Comment: Wowpedia is the up-to-date wiki if you're going to use a wiki.

Comment: @Ben Thanks. I did find the up-to-date info there.

Comment: They don't make it obvious, check out my answer below for info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to its volatile nature, any answer posted about Justice Points is likely to change quickly (at the very least with every expansion, sometimes with a patch).

A good place to look is Wowhead. It's officially supported by Blizzard and is considered the WoW bible by many.

Here is a list of ways to obtain JP (and ways to consume them as well): [Justice Points](http://www.wowhead.com/currency=395)

There are just way too many to list and the formating will probably drive me mad. I will just list a few ways you will get them once you hit Pandaria.

**From patch 5.0 or maybe an earlier patch, you have to be level 70+ to start earning Justice Points.**

- Random regular dungeons (not available to level 90s) - 60 points per dungeon run, no limit
- Heroic dungeon bosses - 100 points per boss, no limit
- Normal scenarios - 50 points contained  in [Greater Cache of Treasures](http://www.wowhead.com/item=92813) per run, not limit

You can check the amount of points you have by opening up your character page, and clicking on the currency tab.

Comment: According to that page, random Burning Crusade dungeon should reward 5 JP, but I've done several and none received.

Comment: What does your currency page say?

Comment: I think you have to be level 70 to start earning JP, at least in this expansion. Don't quote me on it though. I never worry about JP until I am over 85 unless you are thinking about twinking your char at 70 or 80.

Comment: The JP entry doesn't even exist on the Currency page. However I've just found a WoWPedia page where it's stated that only WLK and Cata normal dungeons reward JP. So what you said, not until lv70. http://www.wowpedia.org/Justice_Points

Comment: It does seem that you can no longer obtain JP from regular BC dungeons. WowHead is wrong on that account.

Comment: It's not wrong. You just have to run the dung with a full group of 70's

Answer (score 1):

The first time you start gaining **Justice Point is at lvl80**
You start gaining them from *Random Wrath Dungeons* your reward from completing the dungeons is the justice points and not the money. Also for every Boss you kill you get a x amount of justice points. From then on in Cata and MoP you get justice points from killing bosses which give you x amount of currency as well.

Edit: You also will gain Justice points at 70, only if you run TBC dungeons with a full party of level 70's no higher or lower. Has to be **70**